# Image uploading using another site's API - Bypassing my server

Tags: php, javascript, api, image

I want to use [imgur's API](http://code.google.com/p/imgur-api/) to upload images however I don't want to use my server too much in the act because I'd like to keep bandwidth to a minimum.

The API accepts images in a base64 encoded string or binary.

Also if there's a way to encode images into base64 or binary in javascript that would be really useful to know too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript security restrictions prevent you from reading a local file and doing anything with it.  That will be the reason that you cannot encode a file in Base64 and send it directly to that API.

Does Imgur have an API which accepts a direct file upload?

Comment: Ok. PHP was the other option.

Comment: Javascript also disallows POSTing to another domain.